# sql query was working and now not? insert user ip address into table?

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL query was working fine just 5 hours ago and now it's not? I have not touched a thing.

Can someone please help me get to the bottom of this, it should get the users ip address and store it in the table along with the current time and date, its not inserting anything, would appreciate some help.

Here is my table:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|session_id |    user_ip     |    session_start  | session_end|
|===========|================|===================|============|
|          1|  192.135.123.13|   23:02:20 10:23  | NULL       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my SQL:

```
// GET IP ADDRESS
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_sessions (session_id, user_ip, session_start, session_end) VALUES (NULL, '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', now(), NULL);"; 
 mysql_query($sql, $connection); ?>
```

Comment: Please, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You cannot write queries this way without eventually getting into serious trouble.

Comment: @tadman where is here a sql-inj possiility? You cannot influence the REMOTE_ADDR from outside...

Comment: as i said nothing gets inserted into the table, absolutely no errors, just nothing happens

Comment: that's an `INSERT` statement, and it'll not `// GET IP ADDRESS`

Comment: It is possible to set `REMOTE_ADDR` with clever abuse of headers, but it doesn't matter. Escape **any** and **all** values put into your statement. No excuses. No assumptions. You will get burned in the worst possible way if you write code like this.

Comment: @bwoebi yes, yes you can influence the remote_addr from outside. And it's very easy to do might I add.

Comment: If it's not inserting, there has to be an error. Maybe you have `error_reporting` turned off? Try doing `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Could you show the structure of your sql table ?

Comment: im not sure why it was working fine for weeks and weeks and now its just stoped doing anything

Comment: What about **debug** your query with something like mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); Then I would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Furhermore you are at risk of `sql injection`, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php. You should use prepared statement to avoid any risk

Comment: Put some error handling `echo $sql; $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection); if (!$result) die('Error: ' . mysql_error());` and post output from echo $sql and error message if any

Comment: One way that works on some servers with default configurations is [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). Also, never, ever rule out buffer overflow exploits that could set these variables to just about anything. You **cannot** trust user data. Period.

Comment: is one of your session_id or session_end a NOT NULL column?

Comment: @tadman PHP engine is working after the Network layer, so yes its posible to spoof it, but just with some fake IP addresses. But I agree with you on always escaping!

Comment: @tadman If your webserver is too dumb; no wonder; but normally there shouldn't be never a problem? right?

Comment: @tadman yes, there's a law along the lines of `A thing that can go wrong, will go wrong`. I presume it's from @CaptainObvious lol :D

Comment: p.s.: @tadman with a buffer overflow you also could replace the escaping function. This is no excuse^^

Comment: @bwoebi It's user data. Escape it. Stop fussing about hypotheticals. Never, ever assume user data is safe unless you've validated it or escaped it for the appropriate context.

Comment: @tadman I never considered the remote_addr as user data, only as data about the user...

Comment: It's coming from an untrusted external source, and as it can be specified by the user in the headers, it's user data.

Answer (score 0):

Go step by step.

1. Try inserting the simplest data with values sets to `(1, '127.0.0.1', now(), now())`
2. If it is ok, try adding the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Be careful with case in tables and columns names.

If the 1 does not work in your PHP code, try to execute your SQL insert directly with a MySQL GUI (MySQL Workbench for example), an error should be raised.

If the insertion works fine with a MySQL GUI, then check your connection parameters in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

add this `$user_ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

should be like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_sessions (session_id, user_ip, session_start, session_end) VALUES ('$session_id', '$user_ip', '$session_start', '$session_end')";
```